# Trying to find this typeface or one similar

Tags: fonts, typography, typefaces

[image]

Can you tell me what this typeface is? Thanks! You can see more of it here: https://www.behance.net/gallery/101146789/POVEMENT

Answer (score 0):

This is a unicase typeface, one with the 'a' and 'e' of lower-case. Many fonts have this style but notably [Syncopate](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/syncopate) is a wide, free font in this style. Old versions of Roboto have these forms as stylistic alternates, you might be able to find a downloadable version somewhere too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like NimbusSanExt Regular, where the letters 'a' and 'e' are capitalized.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Please show an example/screenshot of the font  you mentioned so that the accuracy can be determined.  Also I think you made a mistake in your answer. The letters "a" and "e" are lowercase letter forms, not capitalized.